# Communicating over the USB cable from PC to real android moble

Tags: android, sockets, usb

These days I try and try to send data(stream) from an Android-Mobile to a PC VIA USB cable,

I made it good that a socket("10.0.2.2", 6543) on the android emulator sending data stream to a ServerSocket(6543) On a PC , before which I had run "adb forward tcp:12345 tcp:6543".

But when I setup a socket("10.0.2.2", 6543) on a REAL Android-Mobile and a serverSocket on the PC, the socket on the Android-Mobile can NOT send data to the ServerSocket on the PC.

Please help me. Why can't I use the socket on the Android-Mobile to send data to the ServerSocket(6543) on the PC. What is the different between the REAL device and the android emulator. Or , is the IP setted to be wrong? How can I get the IP of the PC VIA USB ADB?

On the other hand, I make it out to send data from a PC to a REAL Android-Mobile as socket and serverSocket.

Thx all for focusing!